How to fix the error while dividing a positive value with negative value in power BI

I calculated the growth between years, but the result was negative instead of positive.
I am having trouble calculating growth using the Dax code in Power BI because the previous year's value is negative. Can anyone help? it will be great

Can you share some sample data and expected results?

I shared a new image, the problem is in the first raw

@SaalimMohammed you need to share input/expected output and the DAX code as well. Help us to help you :)
